# Expectation of the absolute of the difference between two B.M, $\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbb{E}}|B(s)-B(t)|=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}|t-s|^{1/2}$?

Tags: expectation, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I am going through Bernt Oksendal's (S.D.E an introduction with application sixth edition) book, I can do most of the questions without any issue,
but I don't understand how (using my understanding of what I have learned from Bernt up to chapter six)
$ 
Expectation$$$|B(s)-B(t)|=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}|t-s|^{1/2}
$$

Note: I know that I have to use the definition of  Brownian motion, as I have found here on wiki,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion

Could someone please show me step by step as to how to work this out? I do not need just hints.

Note that this specific question isn't from Oksendal's book. Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention, s and t are real, and B(.) is a Brownian motion.

Comment: the Absolute should be |s-t| square rooted not what is above.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I get the absolute square root, but not the square root of 2 over pi

Answer (score 0):

One can easily show that if $X \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ then $E(|X|) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \sigma$. Now observe that if $t > s$, $B_t -B_s \sim N(0, t-s)$. By symmetry, one can argue similarly for $s> t$. Result follows immediately.